# Guitar connection to ACER

Tags: sound, acer, jack, input

my Acer laptop only has one 3.5 jack. When trying to connect to it as a line input, a number of problems arose. The laptop offers to define the equipment as either a headset or headphones, but not as a line-in. When an external sound card is connected, it becomes possible to select the input as a line input, but the problem of connecting the guitar to a laptop remains: when rakarrack and QJack are connected, the ability to watch video disappears, and rakarrack itself stubbornly takes the sound from the microphone at all switching options. there is no line input in the switching [screen switching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkMrt.png) Help me set up the connection, please. OS - Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. An electric guitar doesn't work as an active microphone. You need a direct box, likewise a clever system. If the 3.5 Jack is combo on the Acer laptop, the Ubuntu recognizes it as a duplex out/input in one condition; you use a TRRS 4-segment plug.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, Thank you for your answer. This input correctly work on my laptop when I run windows so I think ubuntu can work with it too without any additional hardware. But I don't know how to set everything up

Comment: `PulseAudioVolumeControl` is a candidate to make it happen. `sudo apt install pavucontrol` if you will.

Comment: problem is solved for external soundcard. it was simple: after manage connection in qjack just restart rakarrack. didn't try it for internal card